# How to use LINQ select something contain string[]

Tags: c#, linq

How to use linq to select something fit the conditions below,
I want select the words JUST contains the string in ArStr[], i.e. a,b,c
In the Wordslist, "aabb" don't contain "c", "aacc" don't contain "b", "aabbccd" contain "d".
So they are not the words I want.
Please help.

Wordslist : 
aabb
aacc
aaabbcc
aabbbcc
aabbccd

ArStr[] :
"a"
"b"
"c"

Expected Query:
aaabbcc
aabbbcc

```
IEnumerable<Word> Query =
from Word in Wordslist
where
   Word.Value.Contains(ArStr[0]) // 1
&& Word.Value.Contains(ArStr[1]) // 2
&& Word.Value.Contains(ArStr[2]) // 3
select Word;
```

Comment: *What is the question*? Your code looks entirely reasonable but you would not be asking the question if you felt that it solved the problem. You have not said what is wrong; what's the problem?

Comment: @EricLippert the problem is that the code he's written incorrectly includes "aabbccd" in the result sequence.

Comment: Are all the elements of `ArStr` guaranteed to be one character long?

Comment: @EricLippert: Since `ArStr` does not contain a `"d"` in it, he does not want to return `"aabbccd"` in `Query`. His current version of the query does not filter out `"aabbccd"`.

Comment: @phoog: Got it. So the desired strings contain *exactly* the characters abc, no more, no less.

Comment: @EricLippert so it seems.  But I suspect that the example is over-simplified and the real requirements may therefore be more complex.

Comment: @phoog ArStr is a one character array in string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a *set* of white-list characters and then filter those words that are set-equal with that white-list (ignoring duplicates and order).

```
var chars = new HashSet<char>(ArStr); // Construct white-list set

var query = from word in wordsList
            where chars.SetEquals(word) // Word must be set-equal with white-list
            select word;
```

or

```
var query = wordsList.Where(chars.SetEquals);
```

Comment: `new HashSet<char>(ArStr)` won't work, as ArStr is `IEnumerable<string>`, not `IEnumerable<char>`.  But, if all the elements in that array are one-character strings, the fix is trivial.  If they are *not* guaranteed to have one character, the problem is more difficult to solve.

Comment: ArStr[] is a string Array contains 8 elements of single character , also contains null i.e. "", when convert the array to chars, error occurred because s is null. Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>'

Answer (score 1):

As you've probably noticed, the query you've written *does* return "aabbccd", because that string contain "a", it contains "b", and it contains "c".

Assuming that ArStr can only contain one-character strings, and you want to return strings that contain *only* the specified characters, so you should say (adapted from Ani's answer):

```
var chars = new HashSet<char>(ArStr.Select(s => s[0]));
var query = wordslist.Where(w => chars.SetEquals(w.Value));
```

However, if the ArStr elements could be more than one character long, the problem needs to be better defined, and the solution will be more complicated.

Comment: ArStr[] is a string Array contains 8 elements of single character , also contains null i.e. "", when convert the array to chars, error occurred because s is null.

Comment: @oreing first, `null` is not the same as the empty string (`""`).  Second, why do you have that string in your array?  What does it mean to ask whether `""` is a substring of `"aabbccd"`?  The answer must be the same for all strings, either "yes" or "no", depending on how you frame the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
    List<String> words = new List<string> { "aabb", "aacc", "aaabbcc", "aabbbcc", "aabbccd" };
        List<string> allowed = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
        var lst = words.Where(word => allowed.All(a => word.Contains(a) && !Regex.IsMatch(word, "[^" + string.Join("", allowed) + "]"))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to evaluate a word if it passes your condition or not:

```
    bool HasValidCharacters(string word)
    {
        var allowedCharacters = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

        return string.Join("", word.GroupBy(c => c)
                                   .Select(g => g.Key)
                                   .OrderBy(g => g))
                     .Equals(string.Join("", allowedCharacters.OrderBy(c => c)));
    }
```

Then simply call the method to get the required list:

```
    var words = new List<string> { "aabb", "aacc", "aaabbcc", "aabbbcc", "aabbccd" };
    var matchingWords = words.Where(HasValidCharacters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to implement it.

I think you can use [String.Trim Method (Char())](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx) on each element , then the empty element is you want .

```
        var arr = new string[] { "aabb", "aacc", "aaabbcc", "aabbbcc", "aabbccd" };
        var arStr = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
        var str = string.Join("", arStr);
        var result = from p in arr
                     let arCharL = arStr.Select(a => Convert.ToChar(a)).ToArray()
                     let arCharR = p.ToCharArray()
                     where p.Trim(arCharL).Length == 0 && str.Trim(arCharR).Length == 0
                     select p;
```